# Facebook Review Process iOS with live app (no simulator build available)

Tags: ios, facebook

How should we submit an app for iOS if we use libs which do not have a simulator build?

The alternative, an app already live in the stores, does not sound good either because it would lead to a bad user experience if users cannot enable the publish_actions permission because it didn't get reviewed/accepted yet.

Answer (score -1):

I uploaded simulator build specifically made for Facebook because my app captures video and uses iTunes library for songs and none of that is supported by simulator.
I embedded one video in simulator build with will be used to test a share workflow in my app. but for a month now Facebook review team keep telling me that they can't reproduce steps for "publish_action".
PS: I provided them step by step instructions ho it's done, supported with screenshots with every step, and tested simulator build just in case and it works.

but for a month now I'm getting same "general" response.

it's irritating :((
if I'll succeed, for what i don't have hopes anymore. I'll let you know. good luck with your submission.

EDIT:
Facebook Review Process for new API 3.0

Finally after 1 month hustle Facebook approved My IOS App for “publish_actions” so I’m writing my steps down so you might avoid this frustration in future.

1. first problem was that I had video Capture and Music library
   Functionality in my app, you had to chose music and shot a Video and
   after that you could upload video where “publish_action” is
   requested,  since this workflow didn’t work for simulator I build
   another version of my app where was a settings tab: where you put
   FaceBook login button (it’s required by Facebook for
   “public_profile” “email” “user_friends” permissions) and gallery tab
   where I embedded video file to show video sharing workflow where
   “publish_action” permission is used (you should not pre-fill user
   fields  “message”  in publish actions “publish_action” because by
   new policy “user message” should be generated by user).
2. another option for for app is to send on app-store version  witch doesn’t makes sense for me at all, (how can I publish app If i don’t have functionality?!).
3. in edit/Notes add/Notes gave step by step instruction how to use
   specific permission.
4. take images of every step (from launching app to published post on Facebook test account) you make for permission use. comment every image.
5. make explanation video of steps you make to revile functionality.
6. use test user in steps you make and send that user to review team.

hope it helps.